# Parsing Lua strings, more specifically newlines

Tags: parsing, lua

I'm trying to parse Lua 5.3 strings. However, I encountered an issue. For example,

```
$ lua
Lua 5.3.4  Copyright (C) 1994-2017 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
> print(load('return "\\z \n\r \n\r \r\n \n \n \\x"', "@test"))
nil test:6: hexadecimal digit expected near '"\x"'
> 
> print(load('return "\\z\n\r\n\r\r\n\n\n\\x"', "@test"))
nil test:6: hexadecimal digit expected near '"\x"'
```

Both of these error on line 6, and the logic behind that is pretty simple: eat newline characters (\r or \n) if they're different from the current one (I believe this to be an accurate description of how the lua lexer works, but I may be wrong).

I have this code, which should do it:

```
local ln = 1
local skip = false
local mode = 0
local prev
for at, crlf in eaten:gmatch('()[\r\n]') do
  local last = eaten:sub(at-1, at-1)
  if skip and prev == last and last ~= crlf then
    skip = false
  else
    skip = true
    ln = ln + 1
  end
  prev = crlf
end
```

It decides whether to eat newlines based on the previous char. Now, from what I can tell, this *should* work, but no matter what I do it doesn't seem to work. Other attempts have made it report 5 lines, while this one makes it report 9(!). What am I missing here? I'm running this on Lua 5.2.4.

This is part of a routine for parsing `\z`:

```
local function parse52(s)
  local startChar = string.sub(s,1,1)
  if startChar~="'" and startChar~='"' then
    error("not a string", 0)
  end
  local c = 0
  local ln = 1
  local t = {}
  local nj = 1
  local eos = #s
  local pat = "^(.-)([\\" .. startChar .. "\r\n])"
  local mkerr = function(emsg, ...)
    error(string.format('[%s]:%d: ' .. emsg, s, ln, ...), 0)
  end
  local lnj
  repeat
    lnj = nj
    local i, j, part, k = string.find(s, pat, nj + 1, false)
    if i then
      c = c + 1
      t[c] = part
      if simpleEscapes[v] then
        --[[ some code, some elseifs, some more code ]]
      elseif v == "z" then
        local eaten, np = s:match("^([\t\n\v\f\r ]*)%f[^\t\n\v\f\r ]()", nj+1)
        local p=np
        nj = p-1
        --[[ the newline counting routine above ]]
        --[[ some other elseifs ]]
      end
    else
      nj = nil
    end
  until not nj
  if s:sub(-1, -1) ~= startChar then
    mkerr("unfinished string near <eof>")
  end
  return table.concat(t)
end
```

Comment: `crlf` is always `nil` because `eaten:gmatch('()[\r\n]')` returns only ONE capture. Probably, you want your pattern to be `()([\r\n])` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That solves it, but I can't accept a comment as the answer.

Comment: Yes, this is a notorious misfeature of SO: comments are not allowed to be accepted, although could contain an answer :-)

Comment: Have you considered posting it as an answer?

Comment: I'm aware this workaround exists :-)

Answer (score 1):

Compact code for iterating lines of Lua script:

```
local text = "First\n\r\n\r\r\n\n\nSixth"
local ln = 1
for line, newline in text:gmatch"([^\r\n]*)([\r\n]*)" do
   print(ln, line)
   ln = ln + #newline:gsub("\n+", "\0%0\0"):gsub(".%z.", "."):gsub("%z", "")
end
```

---

Efficient code for iterating lines of Lua script:

```
local text = "First\n\r\n\r\r\n\n\nSixth"
local sub = string.sub
local ln = 1
for line, newline in text:gmatch'([^\r\n]*)([\r\n]*)' do
   print(ln, line)
   local pos, max_pos = 1, #newline
   while pos <= max_pos do
      local crlf = sub(newline, pos, pos + 1)
      if crlf == "\r\n" or crlf == "\n\r" then
         pos = pos + 2
      else
         pos = pos + 1
      end
      ln = ln + 1
   end
end
```

Comment: That's for compact, but how about efficient? I'm not iterating lines of a Lua script, but rather parsing strings.

Comment: I like your solution. That said, it's not the best solution for my use-case. See my updated question.